# Eclipse OEPE compile needs server restart

Tags: eclipse, gwt, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I have a Java GWT-Spring-JPA project that I am developing in Eclipse with the OEPE plugin. When my server(Weblogic is running), if I compile the code, and reload my webpage without restarting the server, I get a strange error message, and I have to restart Weblogic for it work.

- At one particular point in the code, I get a ClassCast exception to the effect `Cannot cast class A to class A` !!
- Sometimes I get an error during the compile to the effect - Error compiling because `jndi.properties file could not be deleted.` Anyone seen this?
  These errors are really slowing me down! Does anyone have any solutions please?

Any input much appreciated.

Comment: which version of weblogic are you using? Do you have weblogic enabled for development?

Comment: I am using 11g. And yes, it is enabled for development. In fact the situation above goes away if I just restart weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use development mode as you are already and do a exploded deployment from your app diring development in the default auto-deploy directory in your weblogic domain, in the link below you will find general guidance on it.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13706/toc.htm

If you are using Ant you may use the wldeploy ant task for that:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13706/splitcreate.htm#WLPRG182

Well with this environment configured you wont need to restart when you have a static or a page updated it will do it automatically and if you need to force a general classloading update you could have a REDEPLOY file in your split directory(META-INF if using .ear or WEB-INF if using .war) that whenever you do a touch(change it) on it, weblogic will restart your app context WITHOUT restarting the server, updating the class loader for your app and possibly solving your problem.

regards.